# Why WPF PasswordBox is not scrollable

Tags: wpf, scrollbar, passwordbox

Can someone explain to me why the PasswordBox control is not scrollable.

[Preview](https://pasteboard.co/JvgAG2P.gif)

As you can see when mouse cursor comes on PasswordBox, scrolling not work. I added default and custom PasswordBox, both had the same behavior.

This a sample project that I created for better demonstration.

```xml
<Window 
    x:Class="PasswordBoxDemo.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" 
    Height="450"
    Width="600"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="12,8"/>
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="Sample text"/>
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type PasswordBox}">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="12,8"/>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <StackPanel Margin="10" Height="800">
            <TextBlock Margin="16" FontSize="32" TextWrapping="Wrap">
                Put your mouse on password box area and try to scroll by mouse wheel.
            </TextBlock>
            <Label>Text:</Label>
            <TextBox />
            <Label>Password:</Label>
            <PasswordBox Password="123456"/>
            <Label>Text:</Label>
            <TextBox />
            <Label>Text:</Label>
            <TextBox />
            <Label>Password:</Label>
            <PasswordBox Password="123456"/>
            <Label>Text:</Label>
            <TextBox />
            <Label>Text:</Label>
            <TextBox />
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Window>
```

Comment: I don't understand why my question should get down-vote. I put my question with sample code to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: I think people are misunderstanding what you have asked AmRo. Can I clarify that you are asking why the page will not scroll when your cursor starts over a password box? Also sharing binary files (zip/rar etc...) is a no no for a lot of people, consider using a service like https://codepen.io/pen/ to host an example instead.

Comment: @Kodaloid Thank you, But my code is WPF and I couldn't found a service like codepen for sharing sample code. The problem is when I scroll page down and the mouse cursor comes over a password box that page become un-scrollable until the mouse cursor leave the password box area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like the scroll mouse event is suppressed on the password box internally. You could do something like setting `IsHitTestVisible` to false, however this would stop other mouse events from happening as well.

If you just need a no frills work around, add a handler for the `PreviewMouseWheel` event like so:

```
<PasswordBox PreviewMouseWheel="PasswordBox_PreviewMouseWheel" />
```

Give your parent ScrollViewer a name:

```
<ScrollViewer Name="scrollViewer1">
```

Then in code implement the handler callback something like this:

```
private void PasswordBox_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Delta != 0)
    {
        scrollViewer1.ScrollToVerticalOffset(scrollViewer1.VerticalOffset - e.Delta);
    }
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

It's a big ugly, but works.

Answer (score 0):

I put another way to adding scrolling behavior to PasswordBox control. I think this way is cleaner.

```cs
public class PasswordBoxAssist
{
    public static ScrollViewer GetParentScrollViewer(DependencyObject obj)
        => (ScrollViewer)obj.GetValue(ParentScrollViewerProperty);

    public static void SetParentScrollViewer(DependencyObject obj, ScrollViewer value)
        => obj.SetValue(ParentScrollViewerProperty, value);

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ParentScrollViewerProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ParentScrollViewer", typeof(ScrollViewer),
            typeof(PasswordBoxAssist), new UIPropertyMetadata(default, OnParentScrollViewerChanged));

    private static void OnParentScrollViewerChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var passwordBox = (PasswordBox)d;
        var scrollViewer = (ScrollViewer)e.NewValue;

        if (scrollViewer is null)
            passwordBox.PreviewMouseWheel -= OnPasswordBoxPreviewMouseWheel;
        else
            passwordBox.PreviewMouseWheel += OnPasswordBoxPreviewMouseWheel;
    }

    private static void OnPasswordBoxPreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        var passwordBox = (PasswordBox)sender;
        var scrollViewer = GetParentScrollViewer(passwordBox);

        if (e.Delta != 0)
            scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(scrollViewer.VerticalOffset - e.Delta);

        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

```xml
<ScrollViewer x:Name="SampleScrollViewer">
    <PasswordBox 
        [...]
        local:PasswordBoxAssist.ParentScrollViewer="{Binding ElementName=SampleScrollViewer}"
        [...]/>
</ScrollViewer>
```